# How to retrieve data from multiple tables using Subquery?

Tags: sql, database, subquery, inner-join

Suppose we have two tables 
`student`(**studentID**, name, department_ID) 
`department`(**departmentID**, name). 
Our aim is to retrieve the data from both tables using the subquery. I'm trying this

```
select * from department, student
where department.departmentID
IN (select student.departmentID from student, department 
where student.departmentID = department.departmentID)
```

but it returns the cross product of the number of rows of two tables.
This is possible to get the correct result using `JOIN` like this

```
select * from department
Inner join student
on student.departmentID = department.departmentID
```

and using `WHERE` clause like this

```
select * from department, student
where department.departmentID = student.departmentID
```

I'm wondering if someone can tell me how it can be possible using subquery in SQL.

Comment: You seem to understand the correct way to write a query to get this information (the explicit `JOIN`).  I don't understand the purpose of your question.

Comment: How it's possible using the subquery? That's the purpose of the question @GordonLinoff

Comment: You are joining without any predicates - so of course you'll get a cartesian product.

Comment: I believe that @GordonLinoff's point is, why do you **need** to use a subquery?

Comment: @TomH I'm just wondering how it can be done using the subquery? Just finding the new way to do this.

Comment: @Olli can you please let me know how I can avoid the cartesian product?

Comment: which databse engine?

Comment: @user2407394 I'm using mySQL

Comment: I said db engine: mysql or sql server or.........

Comment: Search engine is mysql

Comment: I added a solution... but this problem should be solved by join... Learn subQ with proper examples..

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
select *, (select name from department d where s.departmentID = d.departmentID) as dname 
from student s 
where (select name from department d where s.departmentID = d.departmentID) is not null
```

This problem is however meant to be solved using joins. To learn subQ, use proper examples.

SQL Fiddle: [Test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3487/7)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working for me. I'll be following the proper examples next time

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks.